# Add two numbers represented as digit strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, reinventing-the-wheel, complexity

This algorithm adds two numbers digit by digit using their string representations.

I am wondering what the time and space complexities of the following algorithm are. In particular, I am wondering about the string addition lines, which may make it a quadratic time complexity. In general, what are some ways to improve the performance here?

```
def addStrings(self, num1: str, num2: str) -> str:
    n1 = len(num1) - 1
    n2 = len(num2) - 1
    carry = 0
    ans = ''
    while n1 >= 0 or n2 >= 0 or carry > 0:
        n1_digit = int(num1[n1]) if n1 >= 0 else 0
        n2_digit = int(num2[n2]) if n2 >= 0 else 0
        number = n1_digit + n2_digit + carry
        if number >= 10:
            ans = str(number % 10) + ans
            carry = 1
        else:
            ans = str(number) + ans
            carry = 0
        n1 -= 1
        n2 -= 1
    return ans
```

Comment: Please include a description of the algorithm and what it does in your question  as well in the title, this can help your question to obtain more detailed answers.

Answer (score 5):

Needless to say, that adding numbers in their string form is impractical since modern CPUs are capable of performing regular number addition in a single cycle. This algorithm is therefore interesting only as a brain teaser, if you want to get it to run as fast as possible.

---

The time complexity is indeed quadratic since
`ans = str(number % 10) + ans`
and
`ans = str(number) + ans`
create new string objects (and complexity of this is linear).

Instead of creating a new string each time you can append new characters to a list and do a `''.join(char_list)` at the end. Complexity of adding to the list is constant and `join` is linear but you only run it once, so the resulting complexity is linear.

Space complexity will obviously be linear too.

---

This doesn't have to be a member function since you never use `self` in its body.

Answer (score 3):

## Indexing

You are looping though the characters of `num1` and `num2` backwards.  Instead of using indices `n1` and `n2`, the Pythonic way is to use reverse iterators: `reversed(num1)` and `reversed(num2)`.

## Zip

Moreover, in each iteration, you are taking one character from each.  This sounds like a job for `zip`!

## Longest

However, you must continue until you've processed all the characters of both strings, so this is a job for [`itertools.zip_longest(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

## Zero Filled

When one string is shorter than the other, you use a trinary statement like `n1_digit = int(num1[n1]) if n1 >= 0 else 0` to fill in zeros value for the shorter string.  `zip_longest()` has a `fillvalue=` option which will do this automatically.

## PEP-8

According to [The Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/), function identifiers should be in `snake_case` -- not `bumpyWords` -- so the function should not be named `addStrings`.

## Updated code

Using the above (plus suggestions from QuasiStellar answer), we can create a more Pythonic version of your function:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def add_strings(num1: str, num2: str) -> str:
    carry = 0
    ans_digits = []

    for digits in zip_longest(*map(reversed, (num1, num2)), fillvalue='0'):
        carry, digit = divmod(sum(map(int, digits)) + carry, 10)
        ans_digits.append(digit)

    if carry:
        ans_digits.append(carry)

    return ''.join(map(str, reversed(ans_digits)))
```